# Exclude directories for du command / Index all files in a directory

Tags: find, disk-usage, indexing

My goal is rather simple: I want to create a small database of all files/directories within a big directory.

After looking for a tool suited I couldn't find anything but the good ol' `du`. I figured out that I should use `-b` if I want the number of bytes the files actually have and to use `-a` to list all files. Great.

Now here's the problem: I do not want to include directories in `du`'s output. I would like to have the output like this per file: `size<tab>filename` so I can convert this to CSV or some kind of database. The problem with it containing directories would be that I wouldn't know how to separate directories from files after when I convert/import it to a database and I don't want to end up having files accidentally as directories or vice-versa. I also don't want to end up accidentally counting too much total usage space because when I sum up all files in a directory I already get the whole directory's size, if I add the size of the entire directory on top of that it would be too much.

Here is why I don't want to use `find -type f`... (test directory with 38k files in total, the real one has millions)

```
$ time find -mindepth 1 -type f -exec du -sb {} > /dev/null \;

real    0m45.631s
user    0m25.807s
sys     0m18.946s

$ time du -ab > /dev/null

real    0m0.154s
user    0m0.057s
sys     0m0.096s
```

**I'm open to suggestions of any other way to achieve my initial goal.** I just need a way in the end to "browse" directories and see their sizes (and the sizes of the files they contain) without actually having the filesystem in question mounted. (So kinda like an "offline" baobab you might say)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `du` reports the disk usage of files, not their size (unless you use the `--apparent-size` option of the GNU implementation of `du` (or `-b`, another GNU extension which is short for `--apparent-size --block-size=1`)).

Also note that `,`, TAB, newline or `"` are as valid as any other character in filenames on Unix-like systems.

Here, if on a GNU system, you could do:

```
find . ! -type d -printf '%s,%P\0' |
  LC_ALL=C sed -z 's/"/""/g; s/,/,"/; s/$/"/' |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

To output in CSV format and report the size of all files except those of type directory.

Above, we're telling `find` to output `<size>,<filepath>` in NUL-delimited records as 0 is the only byte that can't occur in a file name. We process that with `sed` NUL-record mode (`-z`) in the `C` locale (again for it to work with any byte value, even those not forming valid characters in the user's locale), by replacing every `"` with `""` (which is the way double quotes are generally escaped in CSVs), and adding a `"` after the first occurrence of `,` in the record (the one after the `<size>`), and one at the end (`$`).

`tr` translates the NULs to NLs on that output as NL is the record delimiter in CSVs. So for instance a 15 byte file called `$'a\nb"c'` would be rendered as:

```
15,"a
b""c"
```

If it's really the disk usage you want, you can replace `%s` with `%b` which gives you the disk usage in number of 512-byte units, or `%k` for number of kibibytes.

If not on a GNU system (`-printf`, `-z` are GNU extensions), you could use `perl` instead:

```
find . ! -type d -print0 |
  perl -l -0ne '
    if (@s = lstat$_) {
      s/"/""/g; print qq($s[7],"$_")
    } else {warn "$_: $!\n"}'
```

(`-print0` is also a GNU extension, but these days, it's found in most other `find` implementations. If not, you can use `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +` instead).

This time, replace `7` with `12` if you want the disk usage in number of 512-byte units.

In any case, note that directories (which is a special type of file that contains a list of filenames with their mapping to inode), also have a size themselves. The cumulative disk usage of a directory as reported by instance by `du -s some-dir` is the sum of the disk usage of all unique files (of any type, including directories) referenced by that directory recursively, plus the size of that directory itself.

Here, if you want to do `du`'s job by hand and be able to report that same size, you'll also need to record the disk-usage/size of directory files, and also record when files are duplicated (when there are several names for the same file, aka *hard links*). So in addition to size/disk-usage and file paths, you'd want to record the device and inode number of the file (`%D:%i`) which is the unique identifier of the file thanks to which `du` is able to tell when two file paths refer to the same file.

You may also want to record the type of the files. And *directory* there is just one of many types of files. There are also *regular* files, *symlinks*, *fifos*, *devices*, *sockets*... (`%y`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As stated in my question, the behaviour of `-b` is what I want. I had no idea that there's a way for find to directly print the file size, that's great! I don't really know sed much and completely disregarded the fact that filenames can contain `TAB` (I actually didn't know that) - Does your answer take care of filenames that have a `TAB` (or comma in this case)? Also thank you very much for the hint of `%y` - I'll definitely use that aswell!

Comment: I just checked `man find` for other possible variables for `-printf`, things like modification time and such is also very useful. I'd upvote twice if I could.

Comment: Okay, after trying it out and adding some more variables I'm very satisfied. Only question left is how to properly and safely put the quotes around the filename, now that I have a total of nine comma separated fields in my output.

Comment: I came up with this: `find . -printf '%A@,%C@,%G,%#m,%D,%i,%s,%T@,%U,%y,%P' | LC_ALL=C sed -z 's/"/""/g; s/,/,"/10; s/$/"/' | tr '\0' '\n'`. Is that safe, even when filenames contain a comma? I think it should but as a `sed` noobie I'm not quite sure.

Comment: @confetti, see edit for what the `sed` part does. In your case, you'll still need the trailing `\0`, and you'll need to add the `"` after the 10th `,`, not the first, so `s/,/,"/10` instead of `s/,/,"/`. Also beware that those `%T@` output something like `1605892440.0446899670` which if interpreted as floats, exceed the precision of most floating point binary representations. Something to bear in mind when comparing timestamps as `1605892440.0446899670` will likely be considered as equal to `1605892440.0446899671` for instance if they're interpreted as numbers.

Comment: Okay good, I had the `\0` in my actual command, just missed it in my comment here. I realized the floating point thing too but figured I can later just get rid of the precision since precise down to a second is more than good enough for me. Thank you a lot for the answer and explanations, wonderful christmas present. :)